# why is the h2 composite primary key not working when duplicate records are persisted?

Tags: database, syntax, h2

I created the table below with a composite primary key using the timestamp and user's ID number.  When I persist a record twice using the same timestamp (hardcoded) and user ID, I'm expecting the primary key to prevent the second record from saving to the database but it isn't. Is something incorrect in my syntax?

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
  EMPLOYEE_NAME VARCHAR (50),
  EMPLOYEE_ID   VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL, 
  EMPLOYEE_ADDRESS VARCHAR (355),
  TIME_ENTERED     TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE ADD CONSTRAINT EMPLOYEE_UNQ_KEY PRIMARY KEY(TIME_ENTERED, EMPLOYEE_ID);
```

Comment: Your definition is fine. But how exactly do you insert the values? With something like `INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES ('a', 'b', 'c', TIMESTAMP '2001-01-01 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES ('d', 'b', 'e', TIMESTAMP '2001-01-01 00:00:00');` H2 properly reports a `Unique index or primary key violation: "PUBLIC.PRIMARY_KEY_7 ON PUBLIC.EMPLOYEE(TIME_ENTERED, EMPLOYEE_ID)`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was within JPA. Since I was providing the ID each time, JPA would update the initial record that got inserted rather than creating a new one.